# my wordpress' webpages are not getting indexed

Tags: html, wordpress, indexing, google-search-console

***Problem I faced***
some of my webpages (of a WordPress website) and my domain is hosted on hostinger, got indexed without applying on search console while others wont get indexed even after multiple application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au5sM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw1Cb.png)
**(I am from a non-tech background so I've tried everything in my knowledge and finally reached out to this community)**

**My Approach**
I've tried re-indexing all web pages, did live testing for all the web pages several times, still the error continues. One of the pages shows the error that the buttons are too close and the text is too small still got indexed.
Whereas the pages not indexed don't show any error.

Comment: Did you add your sitemap to Google Search Console?

Comment: I wouldn’t worry too much if I where you. A simple search on Google showed the exact url you posted. The page is definitely indexed.

Comment: You shouldn’t use the `-site=` flag for this. It is for searching terms within a website. Not for showing search results of a page.